# How do I remove callback parameters from JSONP in Objective C to make it usable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, jsonp

I have the SBJson library at my disposal, but I'm currently only using the NSJSONSerialization class in iOS. 
I am making the call to

http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=dict_api.callbacks.id100&q=test&sl=en&tl=en&restrict=pr%2Cde&client=te

and it returns the following Json file with the parameters.

dict_api.callbacks.id100({...}, 200, null)

From what I can tell, it's the extraneous stuff outside the {..} which is messing me up. Using Objective C, how do I remove everything so only the {...} remains? That way I can go straight to an NSDictionary. I am storing the data in an NSData object if that's of importance. I just started working with Json today so I'd really appreciate some help.

```
NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.webData options:0 error:nil];

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [self.webData setLength:0];
    NSLog(@"1");

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed with error");
    NSLog(@"2");

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.webData appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"3");

}
```

Comment: if you're already using "`NSJSONSerialization`", is "`dict_api.callbacks.id100({...}, 200, null)`" coming back as a value for some key in the "`NSDictionary`" object?  or is that callbacks bit in the raw JSON stream?

Comment: I saw this "dict_api.callbacks.id100({...}, 200, null)" in the raw data format when I NSLog'ed it. when i tried to put it into an nsdictionary with njsonserialization the nsidictionary was null. i also tried turning the nsdata into an nsstring, removing the the extraneous text, and then turning it back into an nsdata, but it still wouldn't be correctly fitted into the nsdictionary. i know that removing the extraneous stuff works because i placed it in http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and it looked fine.

Comment: can you modify your question to show the code where you're converting the JSON stream into a NSDictionary object?

Comment: ok, i added the code where it is actually made into a dictionary. I tried this with the URL @"https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json" which apple specifically made for JSON, and the above code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

It's a hack, but you could just do this (find the first '{' and the last '}'):

```
// Decode the web response data into a string, then:
NSRange begin = [someString rangeOfString:@"{" options:NSLiteralSearch];
NSRange end = [someString rangeOfString:@"}" options:NSBackwardsSearch|NSLiteralSearch];
// Add error checking!
NSString *jsonPart = [someString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(begin.location, (end.location - begin.location) + 1)];
```

**EDIT - BETTER HACK**

The JSON might not be an object, so just grab the parens of the JSONP.

```
NSRange begin = [responseStringJSONPart rangeOfString:@"(" options:NSLiteralSearch];
NSRange end = [responseStringJSONPart rangeOfString:@")" options:NSBackwardsSearch|NSLiteralSearch];
parseFail = (begin.location == NSNotFound || end.location == NSNotFound || end.location - begin.location < 2);
if (!parseFail)
{
    responseStringJSONPart = [responseStringJSONPart substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(begin.location + 1, (end.location - begin.location) - 1)];
}
```